# How to make child elements to display on search and show all elements on click of All using angular2 primeng

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a search input box and alphabets, All. These things to search based on the inputs.
Now,i am searching for alphabet `m`, it gives me the child list but when i click on `ALL`, the elements are not getting reset.
Scenario: Initially click on button towards left of `"p-test17"`, so we are able to see list of child elements.
Now, click on `M`, or search for `"m"` by giving input key, it displays the child elements with m.
Now click on `ALL`, it must reset all, but instead it is not showing all the child elements in `"p-test17"` as it showed in the initial step.

Please help.

TS:

```
searchFacility(search) {
    this.sLetter = search;
    let memberFacilities = true;
    if (search) {
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = this.dtFacilities.value;
        console.log(this.dtFacilities.value,"this.dtFacilities.value")
        this.dtFacilities.value.forEach(m => {
          m.memberFacilities.forEach(f => {
            let mySearch = search.toLowerCase();
            let facilityName = f.facilityName.toLowerCase();
            if (facilityName && facilityName.includes(mySearch)) {
              f.isShowMember = false;
              memberFacilities = false;
            } else {
              f.isShowMember = true;
              memberFacilities = true;
            }
          })
        })
        if (memberFacilities) {
          this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
        } 
      }, 100);

    }
    if (search == "") {
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = this.medicalOfficesList;
      this.medicalOfficesList.forEach(m => {
        m.memberFacilities.map(f => {
          f.isShowMember = false;
        })
      }) 
    }
    else {
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
      this.dtFacilities.value.forEach(m => {
        m.memberFacilities.map(f => {
          f.isShowMember = false;
        })
      })

    }
  }
```

DEMO: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zp74mf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.pipe.ts on line 22 right before `mainArr.forEach(element => {` add:

```
mainArr = mainArr.map(e => {
  return {...e};
});
```

The problem is that when you run `medicalOfficesList` through the `searchMedicalOffices` pipe you are replacing the `memberFacilities` on `mainArr` (which in this case is the `medicalOfficesList`) with a new filtered array. By adding the new code above on line 22 you will make a new (shallow) copy of each object in `mainArr` before you replace it's `memberFacilities` property. That way the original `medicalOfficesList` will remain unchanged.

Comment: No, there is way too much code to just paste it all. If you start from the stackblitz version and do as I've described in the first 2 paragraphs, it'll start working. Just 1 new line of code and those 6 lines to uncomment out. Those are the only changes needed.

Comment: Please check the demo, i have updated the same way as u suggested

Comment: Looks like the demo is working now. After clicking 'M' only 2 children are displayed and after clicking 'ALL' all 6 are children are displayed again.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I suggested. Is it working the way you want it to now?

Comment: Hi, sry i wanted in other way

Comment: Here, based on search, it must give me parent and child starting with that alphabet

Comment: if, child doesnt have word with that alphabet then it should be hidden., when i click on ALL, then i must be able to see all parents and click of that button all children must b shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191959/discussion-between-rocky-sims-and-bhrungarajni).

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.

Comment: Hi, you there need one help